# How my Cryptocurrency Exchange supports Fiat Currency?

Tags: blockchain

Which mechanism is used in Cryptocurrency for converting Fiat currency into Cryptocurrency? Do they maintain stock for particular Cryptocurrency? or they have tie-ups with organisations like (ethereum.org, bitcoin.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Most exchanges stocks some coins so they can be able to send it outside of their platform when a user requests a withdraw of a currency ( either fiat or crypto depending on which user requests ).

Aside of this, pairings of fiat/crypto or even crypto/crypto is usually intern of the platform. Most of time, there is no real transaction on the blockchain when user requests a trade of those.

That's why you have a difference of price beetween exchanges. The relative coherence beetween prices from an exchange to another is due to the fact that if some exchange has a huge difference of price regarding others, moving coins from an exchange to another can become something interesting to benefit of this difference.

Probably platforms have their own internal mecanisms to handle those differences and make coherence beetween exchanges stronger.